# Can some of my answers be converted from Community Wiki to regular answers?

Tags: support, status-completed, answers, community-wiki

You might've noticed that some of my answers are community-wiki. Why? There are 3 reasons:

1. I want to submit an answer, but if it's not good enough, I want everyone to participate and make edits to make my answer a lot more better.
2. With the same reason earlier, downvotes could happen, but as it turns out, all my answers have a score of 0 or more (unless that changes).
3. It's a good way to make things better. If it is a bad edit that they gave, I can just rollback to the desired revision.

But then [**@Penguin**](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/258509/penguin) came up to me after I answered [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/380236/how-can-i-quickly-grab-items-from-a-chest-to-my-inventory/381268#381268) and now I have made a decision to ask moderators to make some of my answers no longer community-wiki, particularly [this one](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/381118/my-horse-cant-be-leashed-unsolvable/381267#381267).

Now here are some questions you might ask because of this:

- *"Is this for the reputation?"* Not quite. Instead of just getting people to edit it freely (if you have enough rep), I can review those edits instead if it suits well.

> If you have more questions, feel free to ask them in the comments and I can put my answer here.

So here are the answers I want to no longer be community-wiki:

- [My horse can't be leashed (Unsolvable)](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/381118/my-horse-cant-be-leashed-unsolvable/381267#381267)
- [Minecraft Pocket Edition giving "Could not connect: Outdated client!" and "Unable to connect to world" error between version 1.16.201 and 1.16.40](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/379673/minecraft-pocket-edition-giving-could-not-connect-outdated-client-and-unabl/381140#381140)

I will continue to make more CW answers if necessary.

Comment: This question will surely get deleted if the action is done (unless).

Comment: Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/08/19/the-future-of-community-wiki/) blog post and the [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts) article for more info...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Done!**  - I've removed the Community Wiki status from the two listed answers for you.

For future scenarios, here's some help center guidance for when posts should be considered for Community Wiki status:

> ### When should I make my answers Community Wiki?
>
> 1. When you want to enhance the "wiki" aspect of your post, so that it can be a continually evolving source of good information through repeated editing.
> 2. When you feel your post would benefit from less concern about voting affecting the reputation of those participating in it.
>
> <sub>[Privileges - Community Wiki | Help Center](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/community-wiki)</sub>